# v-on:change (VueJS) doesn't work with range slider (hidden input)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onchange

I needed to use a plugin to create a Range Slider. (jQuery)

Basically, this plugin works hiding the input text element and updating it as I slide and set a value between A and B.

I tried using v-on:change to capture the value of this hidden input, but it doesn't respond... It only responds when I manually modify it.

How can I make v-on:change work in this case?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in question.

Comment: Try v-on:input event listener

Comment: I do not think your event listener will be called if the range is changed programmatically (by jQuery) - you may need to listen for event directly from the jQuery plugin. And generally it is not a good idea to mix jQuery and Vue ....

Comment: I would also advise you to look for a slider that is using Vue.js, and get rid of jQuery alltogether if possible

Comment: something like this kind of component https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/forms/slider/ (bootstrap & vue works very well together)

Comment: v-model="yourBoundValue". Also use @input="doSomethingOnSlide()" if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, faced the same situation on Vue 2. Please try the @callback="changeHandler"
And You probably will need to use lodash debounce() to handle dragging case.